# Could I use newer API to build my apk?

Tags: android

I want to use the wonderful methods in newer version of android API.
Could it still work OK in lower OS devices?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It really depends what options and methods you are going to use of the new API. Some just aren't available in newer versions. But you can be sure, that almost every Android user got version 2.3 (maybe 2.3.3) atleast.

Comment: you can set say `android:minSdkVersion="3"` and you can set build target to higher api will do..

Comment: Thank you all. I want to use  "setMaxDate"(API 11) in DatePicker class. And I have to change my target API to 11 from 10. Could I?

Comment: It's a perfectly good question. But for the setMaxDate() and DatePicker question, you should ask a new question here on OS. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16519406/193892 is the correct answer for your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No...it will not work on your lower OS devices. But if you still need the functionalities of newer apis, you can go for [support packages](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).

Comment: ... which will work for some but not all new API things. Good answer!